# Hiding a TemplateField in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to enable the `Visibility` of this `TemplateField` after `6 months`. does anybody know how to do that?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Review">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonReview" CommandName="Review" 
           CssClass="ButtonCommon" runat="server" Text="Review" 
           OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm to review this request?')" 
           CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: _"after six months"_ Pardon?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as,

In RowCommand event check the current date with dateaftersixmonth as:

```
if(DateTime.Now >= dateaftersixmonth)
{
 YourGridView.Columns[columnIndex].Visible = true; //columnIndex= column to show  after six month.
}
else 
{
  YourGridView.Columns[columnIndex].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: hi, the `e.Row...` command does not exist in `GridViewCommandEventArgs` so i keep getting error. what should i do?